# .addClass wont override native cell background-color

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a dynamic table that is populated from a server-side database.  When the table is initialized it loops through the table and sets the background color of a specific column based on a condition.

```
function VCColor(){
    var targetTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');

    //Loop through table rows
    for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < targetTable.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        var rowData = '';

    //  item number defines column to filter
        rowData = targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(12).textContent;

        if (rowData == 'N'||rowData =='n') {
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(13).style.backgroundColor= '#ff3333';
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(13).style.color= 'white';
        } else if (rowData == 'Y'||rowData =='y') {
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(12).style.backgroundColor= '#2eb82e';
            targetTable.rows.item(rowIndex).cells.item(12).style.color= 'white';
        }

    };  

};
```

There is also a function built in that will temporarily add a class (editable_updated) which colors the cell background green as a visual cue that the changes actually saved and the database was updated. (code below)

```
$("#dataTable").children('tbody').on('editComplete', 'td', function(event, config){
    var $this = $(this),
        newContent = $this.text(),
        cellIndex = this.cellIndex, // there shouldn't be any colspans in the tbody
        rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').attr('id'); // data-row-index stored in row id

    // Do whatever you want here to indicate
    // that the content was updated
    $this.addClass( 'editable_updated' ); // green background + white text
        setTimeout(function(){
        $this.removeClass( 'editable_updated' );
    }, 500);

});
```

This works wonderfully on all other cells that *do not* have any sort of pre-set styling. However, if a cell that has the pre-set styling is updated; the class does not get added and the cell stays red/green from the initial load.  This is confusing to the users as they think the changes are not getting saved.

I have tried handling the initial load with another class but I couldn't get the page to load correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to use `!important` in your CSS to override the inline styles.

Comment: Why do you have commas inside a function when declaring `var $this = $(this),` instead of a semi-colon?

Comment: @dchayka It's a way of declaring multiple variables at once. `var a = 1, b = 2;` declares `a` and `b` in a single statement.

Comment: @MikeC ahh right, I'm aware of that approach although I never use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `VColor` function adds inline styles to your table cells, you need to use `!important` in your CSS to override the styles.

```
.editable_updated {
    background: green !important;
}
```